# Reraising exception explicitly or passing it on?

Tags: python, coding-style

This question is about coding style.

Say I have a function, *`f`*. *`f`* depends on a condition *`C`*. It calls another function *`g`* as a subroutine. *`g`* also depends on condition *`C`*. If it finds condition *`C`* is not satisfied, it raises an exception. Now, in function *`f`*, should we write:

```
try:
    result = g()
except TheSpecificExcpetionGRaises:
    raise
```

or just plain old

```
g()
```

They both pass on the exception, but method one puts the traceback in the scope of function *`f`*, and method two puts the traceback in the scope of function *`g`*.

Note: the condition of *`C`* not being satisfied doesn't imply misuse of the function *`f`*. Or, in CS terms, the condition C is not part of the problem specification, rather we punt when condition C is false.

<sup><sub>I don't know why I italicized everything and used math terms.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to any language. If you don't plan on doing anything with the exception, or as a result of the exception being caught, then don't bother catching it. It saves you a few lines of code and indentation.

Seeing an `except` block could tell other programmers, who are busy and aren't reading every line of code, "Oh good. CrazyPython is handling this exception" and then *not* perform their own due diligence elsewhere.

If you can't handle the exception, let it blow sky-high. Someone else must handle it, because your code can't, and that's ok.